# Is it ok to to delete and repost a duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, reposts

I asked a question that has been marked as a duplicate. I read a lot of similar questions and explanations in advance but I couldn't find a solution. In the question that should answer my question the asker used a different (not working) approach. There is even an answer that would work for my case however I'd rather consider it as a workaround than a solution since I have seen examples using my approach.

So I would like your opinion in that case. **Would it be ok to repost my question while explaining why other answers didn't help me?** I edited my question but I think it's not getting any attention anymore. Naturally I will remove the old question.

Comment: If you edited your question enough and tell why it's not a duplicate and what you want you could flag it for moderator attention and ask for reopening, explaining why it should be reopened. Deleting the question is not your best option

Comment: Be careful with deleting questions like that; get too many deleted/closed questions, and you'll incur an automatic question ban.  It's better to edit your question, and flag it for moderator attention to be re-opened.

Comment: The last thing you want is an automatic question ban so you best flag it like Blah Blah Grabblesnackers said.

Comment: I see if flagging helps. I guess the `[duplicate]` at the end of the question will likely not draw any attention (even if changed...). Good hint, I'll be careful with deleting questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it ok to delete and repost a duplicate question ?

- Short answer : No
- Long answer : Keep in mind that if the question was closed as duplicate in the first place it doesn't belong here since it's a double. If you post the same question, chances are it will be re-closed for the same reasons. Now, if you ask a similar question with a different approach and explain why other questions were not helpful to you then I guess it is ok to re-post it but guess it is not the same question anymore...this is why you should refer to the *short answer*.

Comment: duplicate = closed? I don't think it's already closed. I'll see if flagging helps, otherwise I'll consider a new question (*not a repost*).

Comment: I think it is yes. I always though questions could be Closed as duplicates. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: There was a fairly recent change that adds "[Duplicate]" to the title instead of "[Closed]" for questions closed as duplicate, but they're still closed.

Comment: @Wooble thanks for the update thats why I remember seeing that ^_^

Answer (score 2):

As has been said in the comments, you have to be careful when doing what you suggest. Do it to many times and the system flags you and you get a question ban.

There is an issue on SO with duplicate questions. Once they get marked as a duplicate the amount of attention paid to them -even if you *do* edit them - drops off sharply .

Your preferred solution would be to edit and flag for Mod attention. However if this doesn't work then you have 2 options.

One: try and get whatever solution was posted to the 'dupe' question so that it fits your needs. Hard, but if it's close not impossible.

Two: Leave your question up, it's a duplicate yes but the system knows how to handle duplicates. Next, sit down and think about your question, think of any phraseology or approach that you could take to make your question clearer and less like the dupe.

Then when you write your new question include the research you did. Point out how much effort you have put into it. Use links and say things like:

> *"I found this question here and it was good, but ultimately my question is different in X way"*.

If people can see the effort put into it. Can see that you did the research and it's clear to them why it's not a duplicate then they are much more likely to help you.

Remember that all the work done here is on a volunteer basis. We like helping by answering questions, ***IF*** we feel like we are actually just answering the question; not doing work for someone for free.

Comment: I understand how SO works and I really appreciate the volunteer help. It's not like my new way googling things, I've done quite some research before. Probably I searched the wrong way and didn't mention my efforts.

Answer (score 0):

As you are speaking of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001470/c-bad-acces-on-vector-begin-using-object-pointers, that question has been already closed as duplicate.

In this case, when the question is edited, it is automatically added to the review queue for questions to be re-opened. Instead of editing the question to add you disagree with the decision to mark it as duplicate, you should edit it to say that you tried the answers given for the other question, but none of them worked for you; you could also made clear in what your question is different from the other, for example adding details about your case (e.g. "I am using quinoa, and not whole grain.").

Deleting a question is a bad idea, on the trilogy sites, since that could cause you to be question-banned. If that happens, you are not anymore allowed to ask questions, and you should gain reputation by answering questions.